# Ajax request does not run after other ajax request

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

When I go to *localhost:52007/Home/Exercise/5* on my page, then display form and pagination. When I click submit button then script is running and all work. But when I want to go to other page instead of click submit button then display other form. And there is problem because when there I click submit button (on second page) then script not running. Only page refresh and my url looks like

> localhost:52007/Home/Exercise/5?items%5B%5D=&items%5B%5D=&items%5B%5D=&items%5B%5D=&items%5B%5D=&items%5B%5D=&items%5B%5D=&items%5B%5D=&items%5B%5D=&items%5B%5D=*

In short, first script does not work when action Exercise return PartialView.

```
public ActionResult Exercise(int? id, int page = 1)
{        
     var model = _db.Tasks.Where(o => o.Tense.Id == id).OrderBy(o => o.Id).Skip(page-       1).Take(1).Single();
     TaskModel tasklistviewmodel = new TaskModel();
     tasklistviewmodel.Task = model;
     tasklistviewmodel.Questions = model.Questions.Split(';').ToList();
     tasklistviewmodel.TotalTasks = _db.Tasks.Where(o => o.Tense.Id == id).Count();

     if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
     {
         return PartialView("_exercises", tasklistviewmodel);
     }
     return View(tasklistviewmodel);
}

public ActionResult Check(string[] answers, int id)
{
     var model = _db.Tasks.Where(o => o.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();
     TaskModel tasklistviewmodel = new TaskModel();
     tasklistviewmodel.Task = model;
     tasklistviewmodel.AnswersUsers = answers.ToList();
     tasklistviewmodel.Questions = model.Questions.Split(';').ToList();
     tasklistviewmodel.Answers = model.Answers.Split(';').ToList();
     return PartialView("_exercises", tasklistviewmodel);
}
```

jquery:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
   var values = [];
   $("input[name='items[]']").each(function () {
       values.push($(this).val());
   });
   var $id = $("#hiddenId").val();
   $.ajax({
       url: '/Home/Check',
       traditional: true,
       data: { answers: values, id: $id },
       type: 'POST'
   })
   .done(function (data) {
       $("#exercises").replaceWith(data);
   });
   return false;
});

$(document).on("click", ".pagination a", function () {
   var $a = $(this);
   $.ajax({
       url: $a.attr('href'),
       type: 'get'
   })
   .done(function (data) {
        $("#exercises").replaceWith(data);
   });
   return false;
});
```

html Exercise.cshtml:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="text-center">
    <ul class="pagination">
        @for (int i = 1; i <= Model.TotalTasks; i++)
        {
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Exercise","Home", new{page = i})">@i</a></li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
@Html.Partial("_exercises", Model)
```

html _exercise.cshtml

```
<div id="exercises">
if (Model.Answers.Count > 0)
{
    <div class="alert alert-info">Twój wynik to: @Model.CountPoints()</div>
    <form>
        @for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count; i = i + 2, j++)
        {
            <p>@Model.Questions[i] <input type="text" name="items[]" value="@Model.AnswersUsers[j]" class="inputForm inputForm-type1" /> @Html.Raw(Model.Questions[i + 1])</p>
            if (Model.Answers[j] != Model.AnswersUsers[j]) { <div class="correctAnswer">Poprawna odpowiedź: @Model.Answers[j]</div> }
        }
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Sprawdź</button>
    </form>
}
else
{
    <form>
        <input type="hidden" value="@Model.Task.Id" id="hiddenId" />
        @for (int i = 0, j = 1; i < Model.Questions.Count; i = i + 2, j++)
        {
            <p>@j. @Model.Questions[i] <input type="text" name="items[]" class="inputForm inputForm-type1"/> @Html.Raw(Model.Questions[i + 1])</p>
        }
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" >Sprawdź</button>
    </form>
}
</div>
```

Comment: You're not stopping the submit click from actually submitting the form. so the browser **IS** submitting it, as it should, to the same page the form was loaded from. you don't have an `action` in your `<form>` tag, so the browser is using all-defaults: `GET`, submit-to-self, etc..

Comment: @MarcB OP is returning false from submit handler. I guess issue is regarding event that should be delegated to #exercices level

Comment: @MarcB I don't click submit button. First I go to second page, and there I click submit button and then script is not running. When I don't go to second page and click submit button in first form then script is running. And then I go to second page then situation is like above...

Comment: @A.Wolff: the indentation is horrible, but the onsubmit at the start doesn't return false, and the onclick stuff elsewhere is limited to `.a pagination`. But since the form IS submitt, since the fields are showing in the url, it's pretty obvious that the submit isn't being trapped/cancelled.

Comment: @MarcB ya indentation is horrible but first handler returns false as i can see it. The submitted URL corresponds to the second time form is submited, as i understand it. OP should delegate submit handler to static parent level. Im sorry as im using tablet, i wont post any answer or fiddle

Comment: yeah, now I see it. but regardless, something's causing a normal submit using a GET query, which is where the form fields would show up in the url from.

Comment: OP you seem to know how to delegate event seeing click one, so do the same for submit handler and check it

Comment: @MarcB thats because exercises content is replaced on ajax success, so bound handlers on any child are lost

Comment: @A.Wolff $(document).on('submit', 'form', function() <- this work, thanks